# How to force language in which reverse geocoding data on iOS is received?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, locale, reverse-geocoding

When i call

```
geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLoc completionHandler:
```

i get all the data (city, county, ...) in a language according to locale set on iphone.

How can i force to always get this data in English?

Comment: Its not possible through public API. You have to use Google Maps API directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not force the language of the geo data retrieved from `CLGeocoder` or `MKReverseGeocoder`. It will always be the system language of the device.
If you want to get the data in English you need to built your own geocoder which is relatively easy to implement with the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Here is a spreadsheet of the supported languages in Google Maps API:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1

Answer (score 6):

For future readers, the accepted answer is not true (at least not any more).

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["en"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
gc.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc) {
    print($0 ?? $1!)

    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    print(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as! [String])
}
```

Calling `removeObject(forKey:)` is important since you want to reset the returned value in `UserDefaults` to the system settings. Some answers make you hold the original value from calling `UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleLanguages")` and set it after getting the address, but this will stop your `UserDefaults` from being in sync with the global Language Preferences in iOS "Settings" app.

Comment: What do you mean by v2.2.0?

Comment: Google placed SDK pod version. `GooglePlaces` from https://cocoapods.org/pods/GooglePlaces.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Google.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work for me either. I'm using objective c in my project but also tried in swift. The value is not set in the user defaults, not even after a synchronize. I just cannot accept/imagine there's no "normal" way for this. Well for iOS versions prior 11. With iOS 11 they introduced a "preferredLocale" parameter which works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

**Update Swift 4**:

Just use this code to force the data returned in English:

```
func fetchCityAndCountry(from location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (_ locality: String?, _ country:  String?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, preferredLocale: Locale.init(identifier: "en")) { placemarks, error in
        completion(placemarks?.first?.locality,
                   placemarks?.first?.country,
                   error)
    }
}
```

You can change the Locale identifier to translate the data into any other language ("ca", "es", "fr", "de"...).

This function can be called, for instance, like this:

```
fetchCityAndCountry (from: userLocationCL) { locality, country, error in
   guard let locality = locality, let country = country, error == nil else { return }
   // your code
}
```

Where userLocationCL is the current user location.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 11 has a new `-reverseGeocode...` method that accepts a locale to use:

```
- (void)reverseGeocodeLocation:(CLLocation *)location preferredLocale:(NSLocale *)locale
    completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler
```

Swift signature:

```
func reverseGeocodeLocation(_ location: CLLocation, preferredLocale locale: Locale?, completionHandler: @escaping CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

Put whatever locale you like. This example just uses the current locale

```
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.location preferredLocale:currentLocale
    completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    // Handle the result or error
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

just put Locale to specific your language

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, preferredLocale: locale, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) in

})
```