# Returning address only in English from reverseGeocodeLocation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, geolocation

My app is geolocation based app and each entry in tableview has location of the entry. The weird thing I found is that when users are from outside of US, the location is written in their language. For example, there was one user from Vietnam and the address was written in Vietnamese. 
I'm using reverseGeocodeLocation like below to retrieve the address of an entry's location. Is there a way to get results only in English? I tried the code out there in other stackoverflow questions, but did not work.

And I am first getting geopoint using Parse. I do not need to do this way, but I just decided to do.

```
 PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
                (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    var location = CLLocation(latitude: GlobalVariable.userLocation!.latitude, longitude: GlobalVariable.userLocation!.longitude)

 CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
    print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription, terminator: "")
                            return}
 if placemarks!.count > 0 {
 let pm = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark
GlobalVariable.detailedLocation =  "\(pm.subLocality)," + " \(pm.locality)," + " \(pm.ISOcountryCode)" }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force language in which reverse geocoding data on iOS is received?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174606/how-to-force-language-in-which-reverse-geocoding-data-on-ios-is-received)

Comment: Got it. Thanks. So I guess I need to use Google API to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameter "preferredLocale" to specific language

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, preferredLocale: locale, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) in

})
```